# How change , optimize or convert images existing on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, optimization

There is a WordPress website that I setup Amazon S3 as images CDN, now site owner asks to convert images to webp, and since images are on amazon S3, non of existing plugins can convert them to webp, I searched and could not find easy way to fetch images from bucket to host, but nothing useful found.

Any idea how can modify images on Amazon S3?

Comment: You would need to download the images, convert them (somehow), then upload them again to Amazon S3. Presumably, the files would be renamed, so you would also need to change the references in WordPress. If you are wanting to do all of this _within_ Wordpress, then you will likely receive a better response at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Judging from your own answer, you meant this question to ask for a tool recommendation. That is off-topic. Compare [ask] and [help/on-topic]. Please [edit] your question to aska  programming-related question accordingly and your answer to answer that on-topic question. Or delete both.

Comment: @Yunnosch I won't, since many people may need the solution, you can feed your ego somewhere else

Comment: Ok. But you confirm that you meant your question so that naming a plugin is the answer, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin solved my problem : https://wordpress.org/plugins/ewww-image-optimizer/

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.